# How to make animations code work in css? [ the code isn't working for me...]

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find my mistake can you please help me?

I have put the `-webkit-` prefixes, also all elements are **Valid**

here's the code:

```css
 div {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;

-webkit-animation-name: easter;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: reverse;

}
@-webkit-keyframes easter {
from {top: 0px;}
to {top: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div>
hi
</div>
```

I expected it to move but I don't know what my mistake is in the code

Comment: What doesn't work? Doesn't it work on other browsers than browsers based on chromium? Thats because of the prefix that only applies to chromium.

Comment: exactly what type of animation do u want do you want to get it bottom or what

Comment: Add this to your code


     position :relative;

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, you should check it as the answer. This will help other users as well

Answer (score 1):

You need add  `position :relative;` to your css

```css
div {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;
 position :relative;
-webkit-animation: easter 5s infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
animation: easter 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes easter {
from {top: 0px;}
to {top: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
hi
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `webkit` prefix will only apply to chromium based browsers. Second in order for `top` to apply you need to specifiy a [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) like absolute or relative:

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;

  -webkit-animation-name: easter;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-name: easter;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-delay:1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@-webkit-keyframes easter {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div>
hi
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Additional information** to the answer of @Hien Nguyen, I would suggest you to use the following syntax when using animations ans working with `@keyframes` in order to increase browsers comptability:

```css
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes easter {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes easter {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}
```

Instead of:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes easter {
from {top: 0px;}
to {top: 200px;}
}
```